# Sed/Awk manipulation of a text

Tags: linux, text, replace, awk, sed

I need to change the last column of a file:

```
dir_/agra_2008_04_07_a  6   scd679  Voice of male
dir_/agra_2008_04_07_a  7   scd680  voice off
dir_/agra_2007_10_01_a  2   scd502  voice over
dir_/agra_2007_10_08_a  2   scd502  voice over
```

to this other:

```
dir_/agra_2008_04_07_a  6   scd679  Voice_of_male
dir_/agra_2008_04_07_a  7   scd680  voice_off
dir_/agra_2007_10_01_a  2   scd502  voice_over
dir_/agra_2007_10_08_a  2   scd502  voice_over
```

Adding underscores to the last column! Anyone? Thank you!

Comment: how do you define "last column"? are they tab separated? what did you try also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/ /_/8g' file
```

It replaces spaces with underscores, but ignoring the first 7 occrences, hence starting with the 8th to the end (`g`). It works if your output has always the same number of spaces until the last column.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have double space as field separator you can use this `awk`

```
awk -F"  " '{gsub(/ /,"_",$NF)}1' OFS="  " file
dir_/agra_2008_04_07_a  6   scd679  Voice_of_male
dir_/agra_2008_04_07_a  7   scd680  voice_off
dir_/agra_2007_10_01_a  2   scd502  voice_over
dir_/agra_2007_10_08_a  2   scd502  voice_over
```

It replace space on last filed with `_`